# How to merge Msi package and .net4.8 version and generate Msi package

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer

I have a requirement to Merge/bundle Msi package with .Net 4.8 executable package and generate MSI package as an output.

I have currently written a Bootstrapper application in wix that generates .exe file, which also has an install condition for .Net 4.8

But the requirement is to generate MSI after bundling

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this is not a good way to do it.

Bring out .net first and then install your msi in another step.

Merging 2 installations in one msi would require you to make a snapshot into a new msi, and therefore you would loose the intelligence of the already built .net installation.

You "could" make a custom action in your msi which installs the .net, but nested installs are deprecated and i dont know if it would really work these days.
I never done it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Custom Action like a power shell script Before InstallFiles

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
            <Custom Action="AddNetFramework" Before="InstallFiles"><![CDATA[NOT Installed]]></Custom>               
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Put the action in InstallExecuteSequence

Some helpers

```
<!-- Get PowerShell exe path -->
        <Property Id="POWERSHELLEXE">
            <RegistrySearch Id="POWERSHELLEXE"
                Type="raw"
                Root="HKLM"
                Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell"
                Name="Path" />
        </Property>

<CustomAction Id="AddNetFramework" Property="AddPSProfie" Value="&quot;[POWERSHELLEXE]&quot; -File &quot;[FOLDER]Scripts\InstallFrwk.ps1&quot; &quot;[FOLDER]Scripts&quot;" Execute="immediate" />
```

Considering your powershell file and ndp48-x86-x64-allos-enu.exe is in location `/Scripts`

Add a fragment for copying file and  `Compressed="yes"` in the `<Package>`